# R shiny updateSelectInput choices for one dropdown menu with choices from another (ie one is a subcategory of the other)

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have a table of data `MegaP2` with Organ type, separated into **Lung** and **Skin**, and then various cell types all of which come from either lung or skin. I have tried to make the available choices in the **Cell Lines** dropdown box reflect only those that come from the selected **Organ** in the first dropdown box.

If I select **Skin** or **Lung** it gives the relevant cell lines perfectly, but then if I try to select the other organ type it then further restricts the cell lines to only those in both organs rather than giving all the cell lines for the new organ selection. It also prevents me from clicking into the cell line dropdown menu to make changes there.

I assume I need some way of getting the organ type to refresh when a new selection is made, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have created lists of choices as so:

```
Cell_type = c("All", as.character(levels(MegaP2$Cell_line)))
Organ_type = as.character(levels(MegaP2$Organ))

Lung_cells = filter(MegaP2, Organ == "Lung")
#Then to remove the levels that have been filtered out
Lung_cells = droplevels(Lung_cells)
Lung_lines = c("All", as.character(levels(Lung_cells$Cell_line)))
Skin_cells = filter(MegaP2, Organ == "Skin")
Skin_cells = droplevels(Skin_cells)
Skin_lines = c("All", as.character(levels(Skin_cells$Cell_line)))
```

My (relevant) ui code looks like this:

```
ui = fluidPage(
  titlePanel(title=div(img(src="cell_image.png", height = 140, width = 400), "The Senescent Cell")),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("OrganT",
                  label = "Organ",
                  choices = Organ_type,
                  multiple = T,
                  selected = "All"),
      selectInput("Cell",
                  label = "Cell Line",
                  choices = Cell_type,
                  multiple = T,
                  selected = "All")
      
    ),
  mainPanel(
    tableOutput("MegaData")
  )
  )
)
```

And my server code is as follows:
I have left in the Select All session updates in case that is causing the problem, as ideally I would like it to work with these also in place.

```
server = function(input, output, session) {
  selectedData <- reactive({
    req(input$OrganT)
    req(input$Cell)
    MegaP2 %>% 
      dplyr::filter(Cell_line %in% input$Cell & Organ %in% input$OrganT)
  })
  output$MegaData = renderTable({
    data = selectedData()
  })
  observe({    
    if("Lung" %in% input$OrganT & !"Skin" %in% input$OrganT)
      choices2 = Cell_type[which(Cell_type %in% Lung_lines)]
    else if("Skin" %in% input$OrganT & !"Lung" %in% input$OrganT)
      choices2 = Cell_type[which(Cell_type %in% Skin_lines)]
    else
      choices2 = Cell_type
    updateSelectInput(session, "Cell", choices = choices2, selected = choices2)
                                    
    if("All" %in% input$Cell)
      selected_choices6 = choices2[-1]
    else
      selected_choices6 = input$Cell
    updateSelectInput(session, "Cell", selected = selected_choices6)
  })
}
```

Comment: Please post some sample data from `MegaP2` using `dput()` in your question.

Comment: Thanks YBS, I am fairly certain I can solve this with renderUI. If it works, I will post an answer and add some sample data so others can see. Otherwise I'll add some sample data, haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should directly use the data table to select the choices.  Perhaps you can try this

```
ui = fluidPage(
  titlePanel(title=div(img(src="cell_image.png", height = 140, width = 400), "The Senescent Cell")),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel( 
      uiOutput("organt"),
      uiOutput("cellt")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("MegaData")
    )
  )
)


server = function(input, output, session) {
  
  df1 <- veteran
  MegaP <- df1 %>% mutate(Organ=ifelse(trt==1,"Lung","Skin"))
  
  output$organt <- renderUI({
    selectInput("OrganT",
                label = "Organ",
                choices = unique(MegaP$Organ),
                multiple = T,
                selected = "All")
  })
  
  MegaP1 <- reactive({
    data <- subset(MegaP, Organ %in% req(input$OrganT))
  })
  
  output$cellt <- renderUI({
    selectInput("Cell",
                label = "Cell Line",
                choices = unique(MegaP1()$celltype),
                multiple = T,
                selected = "All")
  })
  
  selectedData <- reactive({
    req(MegaP1(),input$Cell)
    data <- subset(MegaP1(), celltype %in% input$Cell)
  })

  output$MegaData = renderTable({
    selectedData()
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks so much! Took me a minute to get my head around what you'd done.