# How to make the second selectInput be based on what the user has chosen in the first selectinput in R shiny

Tags: r, dynamic, server, shiny, filtering

I am trying to make a shiny app. I want to have an interactive menu such that by selecting an input "A" in the first SelectInput, R will look at the database and find a list of values that correspond to A, to come up as an option in second SelectInput.

The third selectInput to filter through columns based on the first two SelectInput.

What would the corresponding server code would be if I wanted to do a histogram or table with the result?

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: take a look at the [dynamic UI](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html) article from shiny.

Comment: your question is a bit too general, try to focus on a specific aspect of your problem, list what you've tried and where you got stuck, preferably with a reproducible example. These threads would help [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to make a great r reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64574600/r-shiny-updateselectinput-choices-for-one-dropdown-menu-with-choices-from-anothe