# Hierarchical sidebarLayout() using the selectInput() variables information

Tags: r, shiny

I'd like to create a dynamic and hierarchical `sidebarLayout` using the `selectInput`
variables information. I have a pet information data frame (`myds`) and for example, I choose dog option in `"selectedvariable1"` pet, then in `"selectedvariable3"` the options need to be "collie" or "pit-bull", not "birman" or "bobtail" because the option in `"selectedvariable1"`is a dog, not a cat.
In my example:

```
# Packages
library(shiny)

# Create my data set
pet<-c("dog","dog","cat","cat")
fur<-c("long","short","long","short")
race<-c("collie","pit-bull","birman","bobtail")
sweetness<-c("high","medium","high","medium")
myds<-data.frame(pet,fur,race,sweetness)

# Create the pet shiny dash
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(title="My Pet Dashboard"),  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("selectedvariable1"),
      uiOutput("selectedvariable2"),
      uiOutput("selectedvariable3"),
      uiOutput("selectedvariable4")   
    ),
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("idSaida")
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output,session){

  currentvariable1 <- reactive({input$selectedvariable1})
  currentvariable2 <- reactive({input$selectedvariable2})
  currentvariable3 <- reactive({input$selectedvariable3})
  currentvariable4 <- reactive({input$selectedvariable4})

  output$selectedvariable1 <- renderUI({
    selectInput("selectedvariable1",
                label = "Pet type",
                choices = unique(myds$pet),
                selected = TRUE )
  })

    data2 <- reactive({
    data2 <- subset(myds, fur %in% unique(currentvariable2()))
  })  
    output$selectedvariable2 <- renderUI({ 
    data2 <- subset(myds, pet %in% unique(currentvariable1()))   
    selectInput("selectedvariable2",
                label = "Fur style",
                choices = unique(data2$fur),
                selected = TRUE )
  })

    data3 <- reactive({
    data3 <- subset(data2, fur %in% unique(currentvariable2()))
  })  
    output$selectedvariable3 <- renderUI({  
    selectInput("selectedvariable3",
                label = "Race name",
                choices = unique(data3$race),
                selected = TRUE )
  })
    data4 <- reactive({
    data4 <- subset(data2, fur %in% unique(currentvariable3()))
  })    
    output$selectedvariable4 <- renderUI({
    selectInput("selectedvariable4",
                label = "Sweetness behaviour",
                choices = unique(data4$sweetness),
                selected = TRUE )
  }) 
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
##
```

Please, anyone can help me with this question?

Comment: You should be able to adapt the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64574600/r-shiny-updateselectinput-choices-for-one-dropdown-menu-with-choices-from-anothe)

Comment: Thanks, @YBS, I change my example with your ideas, but unfortunately not solved yet, the same kind of problem happens with `reactive` `subset` creation.

Comment: Please note that you can also use `updateSelectInput()` on the server side, but that requires your previous `ui`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
server <- function(input, output,session){
  
  # currentvariable1 <- reactive({input$selectedvariable1})
  # currentvariable2 <- reactive({input$selectedvariable2})
  # currentvariable3 <- reactive({input$selectedvariable3})
  # currentvariable4 <- reactive({input$selectedvariable4})
  
  output$selectedvariable1 <- renderUI({
    selectInput("selectedvariable1",
                label = "Pet type",
                choices = unique(myds$pet),
                selected = TRUE )
  })
  
  data2 <- reactive({
    req(input$selectedvariable1)
    data2 <- subset(myds, pet %in% input$selectedvariable1)
  })  
  output$selectedvariable2 <- renderUI({ 
    req(data2())
    #data2 <- subset(data2(), pet %in% unique(currentvariable1()))   
    selectInput("selectedvariable2",
                label = "Fur style",
                choices = unique(data2()$fur),
                selected = TRUE )
  })
  
  data3 <- reactive({
    req(input$selectedvariable2,data2())
    data3 <- subset(data2(), fur %in% input$selectedvariable2)
  })  
  
  output$selectedvariable3 <- renderUI({  
    req(data2())
    selectInput("selectedvariable3",
                label = "Race name",
                choices = unique(data2()$race),  ##  use data3() instead of data2(), if you wish to subset from data3()
                selected = TRUE )
  })
  data4 <- reactive({
    req(input$selectedvariable3,data2())
    data4 <- subset(data2(), race %in% input$selectedvariable3)
  })    
  output$selectedvariable4 <- renderUI({
    req(data4())
    selectInput("selectedvariable4",
                label = "Sweetness behaviour",
                choices = data4()$sweetness,
                selected = TRUE )
  }) 
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work, add this to server function and adapt to your code:

```
observeEvent(input$selectedvariable1,{
if (input$selectedvariable1=="dog") {
 updateSelectInput("selectedvariable3", choices=c("collie","pit-bull"))
}
})
```